# Even though equality is the same in reversing the equal sign in Javascript, the result is different why

Tags: javascript

> When I reverse the equation while manipulating the dom it does not output

```
function changeText(chng) {
let text = document.getElementById("app");
  chng = text.textContent;
}
changeText("asasdf");
```

> but this working

```
function changeText(chng) {
  let text = document.getElementById("app");
  text.textContent = chng ;
}
changeText("asasdf");
```

Comment: In the first case, you are just changing the value of the parameter that you have inside your function, and in the second you are changing to an actual DOM element

Comment: @aca I was going to say the same.

Comment: It is not equality, it is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to clarify my comment.

**Case 1: Manipulation of the local variable**

As you can see, the actual value of the `chng` is the same as `text.textContent`, but it's just a local variable, that basically *lives and dies* inside that one call of the function. So indeed, it actually got the value that we assigned.

```js
function changeText(chng) {
let text = document.getElementById("app");
text.textContent = "TEST";
chng = text.textContent;
console.log(chng); //the value of chng is actually "TEST"
}
changeText("asasdf");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="app">
```

**Case 2: Manipulation of the DOM element**

Basically, we do the same thing. Difference is that now we are changing the `textContent` of the actual HTML element, that will keep that value when we leave the function.

```js
function changeText(chng) {
  let text = document.getElementById("app");
  text.textContent = "TEST";
  text.textContent = chng ;
  console.log(text.textContent);
}
changeText("asasdf");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="app">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `=` is an assignment operator, used to assign the value on the
   right to the variable on the left.
2. In javascript the equality operator is `==`, which returns a Boolean
   result.

The context of the code you provided `=` doesn't mean equality, it means **assignment**.

---

- Assignment operator example: `1 = x;` is ***invalid***
- Equality operator example: `1 == 1;` is ***valid***

---

**JavaScript has 3 types of scope:**

1. Block scope
2. Function scope
3. Global scope

---

**Lifetime of Js-variables:**

1. For example The lifetime of a JavaScript variable starts when it is
   declared.
2. Function (local) variables are deleted when the function is completed.
3. In a web browser, global variables are deleted when you close the
   browser window.